# Emacs Auto-complete for systemverilog

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, system-verilog

I am new to emacs.I was trying to add an auto-complete for systemverilog.I tried using marmalade repo autocomplete (http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/auto-complete).I copied the entire files into 
**"C:\emacs.emacs.d"**.

I installed using 
 **M-x package-install [RET] auto-complete [RET]**

But still autocomplete is not working.I read many documents but was notable to solve the issue

Can anyone suggest me an autocomplete file for systemverilog and explain hoe to install that file.My OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: Are you looking for auto-complete or are you looking for verilog-auto?  If you want emacs to help you with automatic module instantiation for example, you need verilog-auto and that comes with verilog-mode. Also tell us what version of emacs you have at hand.

Comment: emacs is 24.3.1 i am looking for autocompletion while I am typing my verilog code...I already have verilog-mode.I want to know how to make autocomplete active??

Comment: I think you will need to download and add auto-complete-verilog package available here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/auto-complete-verilog.el

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Verilog-mode already installed, autocomplete is bound to Alt-Tab by default, it should just work. Or have you already tried that shortcut and it didn't work?